# epstopdf changes the background color of R eps output files created with ggplot2

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, eps

So here is something strange, at least for me. When I generate a eps file using export.eps from HH's export.eps method and then convert it using epstopdf, the background color of the .pdf file changes! But it only happens with plots made with ggplot2! E.g.:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(HH) # export.eps
qplot(rating, data=movies, weight=votes, geom="histogram") + theme_bw()
export.eps("result.eps")
```

[image: EPS generated, nice]

But when I convert result.eps to result.pdf using `epstopdf result.eps`, a strange blue background appears on the result.pdf:

[image: Strange background resulting from epstopdf on a file generated from ggplot2]

This does not happens when I use `plot` function:

```
plot(6:25,rnorm(20),type="b",xlim=c(1,30),ylim=c(-2.5,2.5),col=2)
export.eps("result_ok.eps")
```

Here I use `epstopdf result_i.eps` but the result_i.pdf has white background:
[image: Normal plot .eps]
[image: Normal plot .pdf]

Since I am using `export.eps` on both, I thought it has something to do with how ggplot2 composes the images, but as a noob in R, I do not know what to do to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, for my specific problem, that is, using ggplot2, I have solved it using `ggsave` command:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(HH) # export.eps
qplot(rating, data=movies, weight=votes, geom="histogram") + theme_bw()
ggsave("result.pdf")
```

Therefore I do not need to pass trough the `epstopdf` process and I also avoid using pdf command since I had the problem described on the answer/question posted by Dirk Eddelbuettel. The result.pdf file is nice and does not have the blue background. I was not aware about the `ggsave` command.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are not using R itself to convert to pdf?  See `help(pdf)` for more.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer/question. The answer to your question would be subject for another question. At first, pdf command gave me a 700x700 file. It was not nice as export.eps that seems to export a file with the size of the current device (I mean, when I resize the output screen, export.eps gives me the current size). Then I've used the width, and height parameters of pdf. The dimensions were nice, but the labels and axis disappeared! See the nice image http://imgur.com/dgoYZdp and the one using pdf http://imgur.com/qp4o3MJ